# Converting 16 bit integer into 0..100

Tags: math

I have a system that takes/gives volume (as in an audio amplifier) as a 16-bit unsigned integer. I have another system that takes/gives volume as a integer between 0 and 100.

0 is 0
100 is 65535

What's the math to convert to/from? E.g. in C#.

Comment: Why not simply divide the result by 655.35? (Also the max value would be 65535, because 65536 would be 0 with overflow bit set.)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-multiplication#Rule_of_Three

Comment: Simple math. 100% = 65536, 1% = `65,536`. (`int result = 65536 * 1 / 100`) Your question is very general imo.

Comment: 16-bit int can't store 65536. The maximum value is 65535

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc probably a typo

Answer (score 2):

Dividing by 655.36 is the same thing as multiplying by 100 and then dividing by 65536, which can be done purely in integer arithmetic:

```
int scaled = input * 100 >> 16;
```

That's biased downwards however (and therefore does not ever result in 100), because of the truncation implicit in the division/right shift. You can make it round evenly by adding a bias of 0.5,

```
int temp = input * 100;
temp += 0x8000; // 0x8000 = 0.5 in Q16
int scaled = temp >> 16;
```

Here, 0xfeb9 and up will result in 100. If that wasn't supposed to happen because 100 was an *exclusive* bound, you can of course multiply by 99 instead.

---

The other way around can be done using the same principles,

```
int scaled = ((input << 16) - 50) / 100;
```

This ensures that 100 -> 65535, 65536 is not a 16 bit number so it should probably be avoided.

A largely similar thing can be done shorter but with extra multiplication,

```
int scaled = input * 65535 / 100;
```

Which distributes the results a bit differently but it doesn't make a lot of difference.

Answer (score 1):

Using Vala, which is very similar to C# (a very rough and simple approach):

```
public static int convert_from_unsigned_int_to_percentage (uint16 val) {
    return (int) ((val / 65535.0) * 100);
}

public static uint16 convert_from_percentage_to_unsigned_int (int val) {
    return (uint16) ((val / 100.0) * 65535);
}

int main (string[] args) {
    print ("test1 65535 -> ? = %d\n", convert_from_unsigned_int_to_percentage (65535));
    print ("test1 32500 -> ? = %d\n", convert_from_unsigned_int_to_percentage (32500));
    print ("test1 100%% -> ? = %d\n", convert_from_percentage_to_unsigned_int (100));
    print ("test1 50%% -> ? = %d\n", convert_from_percentage_to_unsigned_int (50));

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
./volume 
test1 65535 -> ? = 100
test1 32500 -> ? = 49
test1 100% -> ? = 65535
test1 50% -> ? = 32767
```

Comment: already 2 down votes, the rage continues... The question is very specific on the goal and the answers language of choice if left to the choice of who answers it. Thanks to the upvoter for support. Think and understand before down voting, luckily you stay anonymous otherwise your ignorance would be public.

Comment: Maybe people don't like Vala?

Comment: Should not be a reason to down vote a question. They could comment. If needed i would remove it but we're are here trying to help and all this down vote rage has made me question if i should continue contributing or just go into lurk mode...

Comment: There's no point in writing math in a different language than the question. Just write the math. Calling all downvotes "rage" probably isn't helping your cause, either.

Comment: @Ryan Indeed but i've been observing a pattern where people will just down vote without even reading the answer. I would not state it if I didn't had that feeling. Thanks for feedback though. I answered with code because (user) tig requested the answer in code. If you notice my comment on his question, i've put a link to wiki math explanation. GL Peace